# Need help broadcasting logcat from random letter generator in android studio

Tags: java, android

I am working on an app that is supposed to generate random characters via a broadcast. I need to broadcast the random characters generated by my custom service, so that the main activity registered to intercept the broadcast can get the random numbers and display them on an EditText. Everything works fine besides the characters actually being displayed on the EditText. The string characterDisplay isn't being used for some reason. Can you help me with this?

```
BroadcastReceiver myReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String characterToDisplay = intent.getStringExtra("rand_char");
            Toast.makeText(context,"Broadcast received", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    };
```

**bold**
*italic*

Comment: Please don't repeat questions. Simply editing your original post with any new information you have, or any new code you've tried, will bump it to the top of the active queue.

Comment: Please undelete your original question. It has more, necessary information, and I'm currently helping you there.